# Make a standard POST form validation in Knockout

Tags: mvvm, knockout.js

To allow to make validation of form before submit, 
I want to make a simple HTTP POST submit from the Submit method i defined.

**Code of the view :**

```
   <form data-bind="submit: BaseSubmit" id="FormId">
      <!-- Some rows ... -->
      <button type="submit">Create</button>
   </form>
```

**And of the JS behavior**

```
this.viewModel.BaseSubmit = 
   function(formElements) {
      //Here the code to make the submit redirection
    };
```

Is this possible ?
Thanks by advance.

Comment: Do you want to make an AJAX POST?

Comment: Hm i would prefer a standard submit. But if it's not possible, i will go with a $.ajax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upon successful validation, make sure and `return true` from your binding handler:

```
this.viewModel.BaseSubmit = 
    function(formElements) {
        if (/* validation is successful */) {
            return true;
        } else {
            /* handle validation errors */
        }
    };
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/CCNtR/22/

From [the documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/event-binding.html#note_3_allowing_the_default_action):

> By default, Knockout will prevent the event from taking any default action. For example if you use the event binding to capture the keypress event of an input tag, the browser will only call your handler function and will not add the value of the key to the input element’s value. A more common example is using the click binding, which internally uses this binding, where your handler function will be called, but the browser will not navigate to the link’s href. This is a useful default because when you use the click binding, it’s normally because you’re using the link as part of a UI that manipulates your view model, not as a regular hyperlink to another web page.
>
> **However, if you do want to let the default action proceed, just return true from your event handler function**

Comment: At the instant i saw your answer, i was thinking "Of course, to allow an onSubmit, the related method should return true"... same principle here ...
Thanks for your help.